# Can't find a good solution to select from 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

so i have this problem where i need to select from 2 different tables in the same MySQL query,

here's the query:

```
SELECT * FROM minigame_players WHERE lobby='$game_id'
```

this works perfectly, but i would like it to also select `permissions` from the table `users` where `username` = the returned value from the query below. As an example, let's say that the query below returns the value `John`, then i would like to (in the same query) select `permissions` from `users` where `username` = `John` - i have tried looking it up from multiple websites but i can't find a good solution.

Comment: you should research `join` queries - also, you're open to SQL injection

Comment: the variable `$game_id` has already been put through the mysql string escape command, so it's safe

Comment: Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: how could an SQL injection occur if i have escaped the variable, could you give an example of an input that would cause an SQL injection?

Comment: Show us the schema for the 2 tables, or at least tell us which column links both these tables

Comment: @AlexKV show us how you make it "safe" - much easier to go from there :)

Comment: Or just read the answer in the link

Comment: I can show you that soon, but i'd really need to get this solved as soon as possible, i don't understand how JOIN works - it's too complicated for me :(

Comment: @Strawberry Is it that close to Christmas :)

Comment: Could you help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT mg.username, us.role 
FROM minigame_players mg
INNER JOIN users us ON us.username = mg.username 
WHERE mg.lobby= :game_id
```

Note: use prepared statement and parameterized queries at all time. Consider [this famous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200256/how-can-i-avoid-sql-injection-attacks) for more details.

Answer (score -3):

use a subQuery like this may help, i could suggest you using mysql JOIN too if you mapped these tables.

you can also use UNION, but you should have the same number of columns in these tables.

```
SELECT  (
  SELECT *
  FROM permissions
  where user = ?
 ) AS permission,
 (
  SELECT * 
  FROM minigame_players 
  WHERE lobby = ?
 ) AS player
)
```

use prepared statement to prevent sql injection.

Comment: "where user = toto" are we assuming that the username is toto or is toto a variable or something in MySQL? I'm not so experienced when it comes to MySQL..

Comment: toto was a value, but i forget to write script as prepared statement, perhaps you should share your tables schema or php code